# JQ from curl output

Tags: json, curl, jq

I have a json output

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "success": true,
  "data": [{
      "id": "66",
      "subnet": "0.0.0.0",
      "mask": "",
      "sectionId": "1",
      "description": "THA4",
    },
    {
      "id": "72",
      "subnet": "1.2.3.4",
      "mask": "",
      "sectionId": "1",
      "description": "ALF5",
    },
],
}
```

I'd like to have the output like this based on the description and subnet:

```
THA4  
0.0.0.0  
ALF5  
1.2.3.4
```

and want to have like this too:

```
THA4,0.0.0.0  
ALF5,1.2.3.4
```

With my query:

```
jq '.data | .[].description,.[].subnet'
```

I can get only like this:

```
0.0.0.0  
1.2.3.4  
THA4  
ALF5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Strictly speaking, the sample "JSON" is not valid JSON. The following assumes that the superfluous commas have been removed.
2. To obtain the desired linear listing, just hoist the `[]`:

   jq -r '.data[] | (.description, .subnet)'

produces:

```
THA4
0.0.0.0
ALF5
1.2.3.4
```

3. One way to get CSV is to use `@csv`:

   .data[]
   | [.description, .subnet]
   | @csv

produces quoted values:

```
"THA4","0.0.0.0"
"ALF5","1.2.3.4"
```

4. If you don't want the individual values to be quoted:

`.data[] | "\(.description), \(.subnet)"`

Comment: Sorry, the 4th one doesn't work, it gives back like this:  (.description), (.subnet)